# How to use ElementTreeSelectionDialog in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to use the ElementTreeSelectionDialog but I am not sure how to set my input. 
I have an xml file which emulates the tree structure of the dialog.

I have no idea how to convert that into a variable which can be set into a input for the ElementTreeSelectionDialog.

Answer (score 1):

Have look at some example on selection dialogs [here](http://www.eclipse-tips.com/how-to-guides/5-selection-dialogs-in-eclipse).

You need to implement ITreeContentProvider and ILabelProvider and use these implementations while creating ElementTreeSelectionDialog class.

Check the sources of `org.eclipse.ui.model.WorkbenchContentProvider`(which implements `ITreeContentProvider`) and `org.eclipse.ui.model.WorkbenchLabelProvider`(implements `ILabelProvider`) at http://grepcode.com/ for reference.

Comment: If you have the Eclipse SDK installed you can read the source of things in Eclipse much more easily than a web site.

Comment: Well i've made a dialog that works fine using the example. I am just not sure how to replace this line. dialog.setInput(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()); with something I want. Could you show me a example of where the input is lets say these three strings. "one" "two" "three"

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XML parser say DOM parser (assuming that your XML is not very huge) to read the XML and get the root Document object. This object can be passed to the setInput() method for the dialog and you may have to implement the ITreeContentProvider and a label provider accordingly. In case you are not familiar with DOM parsers a lot of material can be found online on that.